# unable to connect springboot and kafka application when deploying to 2 different servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

this is kafka docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka0:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.2.1"
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '27017:27017'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://kafka0:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://kafka0:27017
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_BOB://kafka0:29092,LISTENER_FRED://localhost:9092,LISTENER_ALICE://10.255.250.160:27017
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_BOB:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_FRED:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_ALICE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_BOB
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100

  kafkacat:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafkacat
    command: sleep infinity
```

here is the bootstrap-server configuration of the springboot application:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 'http://10.255.250.160:27017'
```

this is the error when i deploy the springboot application:

```
emap-sync  | 2022-07-04 10:10:38.842  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-78b615fa-7c98-4ea9-b73e-6472e88ebe0a-3, groupId=78b615fa-7c98-4ea9-b73e-6472e88ebe0a] Node -1 disconnected.
emap-sync  | 2022-07-04 10:10:38.842  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-78b615fa-7c98-4ea9-b73e-6472e88ebe0a-3, groupId=78b615fa-7c98-4ea9-b73e-6472e88ebe0a] Connection to node -1 (/10.255.250.160:27017) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
emap-sync  | 2022-07-04 10:10:38.842  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-78b615fa-7c98-4ea9-b73e-6472e88ebe0a-3, groupId=78b615fa-7c98-4ea9-b73e-6472e88ebe0a] Bootstrap broker 10.255.250.160:27017 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Comment: are you sure your server is running on `http://10.255.250.160:27017`? can you check if its protocol is `http` or something else?

Comment: 27017? Kafka is not Mongo... Two of your advertised listeners are the exact same hostname, so you don't need different ports for it. You'll want `LISTENER_ALICE://0.0.0.0:<port>`. And Kafka is not an HTTP protocol